# operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full

Tags: c++, networking, windows-server-2008-r2, unc

I have a machine running multiple applications which constantly perform UNC access (`\\server-ip\share`) so:

```
std::ifstream src(fileName, std::ios::binary);
std::ofstream dst(newFileName, std::ios::binary);
CopyFromRemote(ifstream &src, ofstream &dst);
dst.flush();
dst.close();
src.close();

void CopyFromRemote(ifstream src, ofstream dst)
{
  char buffer[8192]; // read 8KB each chunk
  while (src.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer)))
  {
    dst.write(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    // Here there is code that checks that some timer !> max read time so as 
    // to not be stuck if there is network issue with this src.
  }
  if (src.eof() && src.gcount() > 0)
  {
    dst.write(buffer, src.gcount()); // few bytes left
  }
}
```

As can be seen the network is heavily strained by traversing it for each 8KB (files are several MB large). The benefit here is the ability to abort a file copy in case it takes too long from specific source.

The problem I'm facing is after several days all UNC become non-accessible from this machine with error above. I'm not sure what the source of the problem is but it's sporadic & hard to nail. When the problem happens the 1st line fails (std::ifstream src...). **telnet** also stops to work.

Also: When killing the applications the UNC is accessible again. When restarting the processes the UNC is immediately not accessible again. Restarting the machine solves the problem for several days.

Initially I thought it was [Port exhaustion](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/10/29/port-exhaustion-and-you-or-why-the-netstat-tool-is-your-friend/) but `netstat` does not reveal too many connections or hanging connections and the task manager performance tab does not show abnormal figures. TcpQry shows normal TCP/UDP mapping numbers.

Also: Packet capture shows there is no request when problem happens (request not reaching network). Event viewer does not reveal anything. Did following registry changes although this would probably just delay problem not eliminate it but anyway it didn't help:

Find the `autodisconnect` value in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters`. If it's not there, create a new `REG_DWORD` called `autodisconnect`. Edit the value as Hexadecimal and set it to `ffffffff`.

Find `KeepConn` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanworkstation\parameters`. If it doesn't exist create it as a `REG_DWORD` value and assign it the value 65534.

Find `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters` and create a new `DWORD` value named `MaxUserPort`. Set the value to 65534.

Comment: What exactly is giving the error. Your programm or the remote read/write or the operating system?

Comment: It sounds a lot like a memory fragmentation issue. But if it would be in your application, a restart would solve it. So you might hit a problem in your network stack. Trying to unload/load your network driver might help if possible.

Comment: Error is in application. When problem happens requests don't arrive to network. Only restarting the machine solves for several days.

Comment: `ifstreams` do not open sockets. That is why i doubt, that the application is throwing the error. The underlying filesystem will most likely throw this error.

Comment: Can TCP stack be reset without reboot? (BTW network driver disable/enable didn't help)

Comment: In principal it should be possible. For linux you can load and unload modules into the kernel and for windows there should be the same features.
But unloading the tcp stack may seriously mess up the whole system, because many programs communicate over tcp/ip locally

Comment: Your copy loop is incorrect. You should only write the actual number of bytes that were read. You are liable to write junk at any time, and almost certainly at the end of the stream.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eventually this was due to Microsoft OS bug. Since machine is an offline machine it does not get regular updates automatically. Installing all OS updates solved the problem.

Comment: What OS bug? This is not credible. What else did you fix in the meantime?

Comment: U r pretty presumptuous to declare this is not credible. Nothing else was fixed. MS admitted to have a kernel socket leak on other server flavors (article 2577795). Bottom line installing all updates solved issue. Have integrity to take back your comment Mr EJP & have a nice day.

Comment: When you go so far as to claim an OS bug is responsible it is imcumbent on you to provide chapter and verse, as such claims are inherently implausible. And presumptuous.